# How to Create Nested Level Map Schema Structure in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, schema

I was trying to create an object structure with dynamic year and months inside it & followed by data inside each month.

**My expectation**

```
{
    "2022": {
            "january": {
                    "cards":  [
                        {
                                "name":"Card Name",
                                "amount":100,
                                "date":  "2021-07-06T20:30:00.000Z" 
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "february": {
                    "cards":  [
                        {
                                "name":"Card Name",
                                "amount":100,
                                "date":  "2021-07-06T20:30:00.000Z" 
                        }
                    ]
                }
        },
       "2023": {
            "March": {
                    "cards":  [
                        {
                                "name":"Card Name",
                                "amount":100,
                                "date":  "2021-07-06T20:30:00.000Z" 
                        }
                    ]
                }
        }, 
}
```

I have found one level on the map scheme

```
const DynamicSchema = new Schema({
    year: {
        type: Map,
        of: String,
    }
});
```

I was able to create this ✅

```
   {
        "year": {
             "2022": "test"
            }
    }
```

When trying with the below schema but ended up with an error❌

```
const DynamicSchema = new Schema({
    year: {
        type: Map,
        of: [Map],
        month: {
            type: Map,
            of: [Map],
        }
    }
});
```

Request payload:

```
{
    "year": {
         "2022": {
             "month": "34"
            }
        }
}
```

> "error": "Cast to string failed for value "{ month: '34' }" (type Object) at path "year.$*""

Is my structure possible with MongoDB or not? if yes any hint would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your payload itself is wrong:

```
{
    "year": {
         "2022": {
             "month": "34"
            }
        }
}
```

You have defined your schema like this:

```
const DynamicSchema = new Schema({
    year: {
        type: Map,
        of: [Map],
        month: {
            type: Map,
            of: [Map],
        }
    }
});
```

Notice that `month` is defined as a map here. However, you are passing a string for it `34`, in your payload. So, the conversion of `34` to map fails, hence you get the error. Try sending a map, in your payload:

```
{
        "year": {
             "2022": {
                 "month": {
                    "Jan": "34"
                  }
                }
        }
}
```